# Display a specific existing widget in a WordPress theme, bypassing sidebars

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, widget

Is it possible to display an existing widget (configured via the widgets control panel) in a WordPress theme bypassing the whole "sidebar" thing? It may not be good practice, but I sort of expect this to be possible - and can't find a way to do it.

I've read about "[the_widget](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget)", but looks like this function call creates a new one (complete with new title, text etc) instead of reusing a widget that I have configured in the control panel.

If this is not possible - I'll have to use the sidebars, but hoped to avoid doing it in several specific places, seems overkill.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Just look on the specific widget's code, you'll find the function that the sidebar calls, call that function right on the theme passing the parameters you need in an array.

Comment: Hmm, do you know where to find such code for the Text widget? Or how to see how the sidebar calls it?

Comment: The code is found on wp-includes/default-widgets.php, around line 368.